# Is the footage at the end of the merchandising video in S05E08 referencing another episode?

Tags: its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia

At the end of the [*It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472954/) episode "Paddy's Pub: Home of the Original Kitten Mittens" (S05E08) the gang shows their merchandising video to a bunch of possible investors. But due to time problems they weren't able to properly cut it and thus the video suddenly ends with a totally unrelated scene showing *Frank* spray a woman, probably *Sweet Dee*, with a fire-extinguisher with a burning house in the background.

[image]

**I wonder if this scene is referencing a specific episode**, but right now I can't get my head around which one that would be. Or is this just a random scene supposed to hint at some other non-documented adventure of the gang? (And is this actually supposed to be *Paddy's Pub* in the background?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. This is from episode 8 in season 3 where Mac, Charlie and Frank try to be local news reporters and make Sweet Dee save some kittens from a burning building (which explains why they have this on tape). It was called, well, [*Frank Sets Sweet Dee on Fire*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1028242/combined). :) Here's the aftermath:

[image]

Comment: What the hell? This is really the only (really, the only) episode from all the past seasons I have *not* seen, I think. Oh my, now I feel inclined to delete that stupid question.